# Unreal engine in Mac osx not running

Tags: macos, unreal-engine4

I have tried the following things:

1. Download the latest launcher from epic games; Launcher not Starting up when clicking the epic games launcher.
2. Download the source from github; its installed but dont launch

I'm also able to generate xcode project from a uproject.
But again not running. Nothing starts up.

Answer (score 0):

I think the project files have recently been a little messed up - the dependencies do not seem to be quite right.

You have to explicitly build UnrealHeaderTool, UnrealLightmass and ShaderCacheTool once.  This will bootstrap things enough to open up the editor.

To select the different schemes click that UE4 button at the top left - it will reveal a menu you can select the other tools from.  Then Build (Command B) each one.

The above was true with version 4.13.x of the Engine.

Side note - Xcode 8 is currently broken with Unreal 4.13.  You will need to either downgrade to 7.3.1 or wait for the fix in 8.1.